# Azure AD B2C React Client .NET 5 API

Tags: c#, reactjs, azure-ad-b2c

I am having a problem configuring a React client accessing a .NET 5 web API using Azure AD B2C.  I reviewed the following documents;

- [Register apps in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/register-apps)
- [Register a single-page application (SPA) in Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa)
- [Add a web API application to your Azure AD B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-api-application?tabs=app-reg-ga)
- [Single-page application: Acquire a token to call an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=react)
- [Enable authentication in your own web API by using Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient)

I ended up using the examples shown in the last document and using the configuration settings for the node.js API server in my .NET 5 Web API;

**React Configuration**

```js
import { LogLevel } from "@azure/msal-browser";

export const b2cPolicies = {
    names: {
        signIn: "b2c_1_signin", 
        signInStaff: "b2c_1_signupin_staff" 
    },

    authorities: {
        signIn: {
            authority: "https://<b2cTenantName>.b2clogin.com/<b2cTenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signin", 
        },
        signInStaff: {
            authority: "https://<b2cTenantName>.b2clogin.com/<b2cTenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupin_staff"
        }
    },

    authorityDomain: "<b2cTenantName>.b2clogin.com" 
}

export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "ec0441a4-89ac-1111-1111-111111111111",
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signIn.authority,
        knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain],
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
                if (containsPii) return;
                level = LogLevel.Verbose;

                switch (level) {
                    case LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        return;
                    default:
                        console.log(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid", "offline_access"]
};

export const loginRequestStaff = {
    scopes: ["openid", "profile"]
};

 export const protectedResources = {
    portalApi: {
        scopes: ["https://<b2cTenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/PortalClient/access_as_user"],
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/Dashboard",
    },
    portalApiStaff: {
        scopes: ["https://<b2cTenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/PortalClient/access_as_staff"],
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/Dashboard",
    }
}
```

**.NET 5 AppSettings.json**

```cs
{
    ...
    
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://<b2cTenantName>.b2clogin.com",
        "Domain": "<b2cTenantName>.onmicrosoft.com",
        "ClientId": "ec0441a4-89ac-1111-1111-111111111111",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignIn"
    },

    ...
}
```

**Portal API Registration**

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Application (Client) ID | d1a138a9-2379-1111-1111-111111111111 |
| Directory (Tenant) ID | 6c977334-b859-2222-2222-222222222222 |
| Redirect URIs | http://localhost:3000 |
| Certificates & Secrets | None |
| API Permissions (all have Admin consent) | Microsoft Graph - offline_access, openid |
| Application ID URI | https://.onmicrosoft.com/PortalApi |
| Exposed APIs (scopes) | access_as_staff, access_as_user |

**Portal Client Registration**

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Application (Client) ID | ec0441a4-89ac-1111-1111-111111111111 |
| Directory (Tenant) ID | 6c977334-b859-2222-2222-222222222222 |
| Redirect URIs | http://localhost:3000/Dashboard |
|  | http://localhost:3000 |
| Certificates & Secrets | None |
| API Permissions (all have Admin consent) | Microsoft Graph: - offline_access, openid |
|  | Portal API - access_as_staff, access_as_user |

**MSAL Login & Access Token Code**

```js
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { msalConfig, b2cPolicies, protectedResources, loginRequest, loginRequestStaff } from "./authConfig";

let msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
export const getMsalInstance = () => msalInstance;

export const login = () => {
    msalInstance.config.auth.authority = b2cPolicies.authorities.signIn.authority;
    msalInstance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
}

export const loginAsStaff = () => {
    msalInstance.config.auth.authority = b2cPolicies.authorities.signInStaff.authority;
    msalInstance.loginRedirect(loginRequestStaff);
}

export const getAccessToken = async (accessToken, isStaffUser) => {
    const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
    if (accounts.length === 0) return null;

    let _accessToken = {...accessToken};

    if (_accessToken.token == null || _accessToken.expires <= Date()) {
        const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
            account: accounts[0],
            scopes: isStaffUser ? protectedResources.portalApiStaff.scopes : protectedResources.portalApi.scopes
        });
        const expiryDt = new Date(0).setUTCSeconds((response.idTokenClaims.exp));
        _accessToken = { token: response.idToken, expires: expiryDt };
    }
    return _accessToken;
}
```

**.NET 5 Web API Startup.cs**

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                }, options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });

            services.AddAuthorization();
            ...
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            ...
        }
    }
```

When acquiring the access token in the MSAL code I get the following response in `response.idToken`;

```json
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk"
}.{
  "exp": 1669793111,
  "nbf": 1669789511,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "https://<b2cTenantName>.b2clogin.com/6c977334-b859-2222-2222-222222222222/v2.0/",
  "sub": "3a35cfce-de55-4217-9c33-217f14639578",
  "aud": "ec0441a4-89ac-1111-1111-111111111111",
  "nonce": "ce9b5c4f-010d-43cc-9dce-861e6a087489",
  "iat": 1669789511,
  "auth_time": 1669789496,
  "idp_access_token": "eyJraWQiOiItVWRTSVB...7bBGxGDzNQWqw",
  "idp": "https://<idp>/oauth2/auskoi3basJBCcDOy1t7",
  "given_name": "John",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "oid": "3a35cfce-de55-4217-9c33-217f14639578",
  "emails": [
    "John.Doe@my-company.com.au"
  ],
  "tfp": "B2C_1_SignUpIn_Staff"
}.[Signature]
```

and if I then decode the `idp-access-token` I get;

```json
{
  "kid": "-UdSIPeUmX7e4pqpXRBb7IXu3bCLsQo0hU67PYDhdfM",
  "alg": "RS256"
}.{
  "ver": 1,
  "jti": "AT.r_KbqlRqqur1gxf9u5S8VReP2awA58YjtIfKiBdLokQ",
  "iss": "https://<my-company>/oauth2/auskoi3basJBCcDOy1t7",
  "aud": "Company-CustomerPortal",
  "iat": 1669789481,
  "exp": 1669793081,
  "cid": "0oakoicxjrL5IMsmd1t7",
  "uid": "00ua37oxlxRdmbFgb1t7",
  "scp": [
    "groups",
    "profile",
    "openid"
  ],
  "auth_time": 1669789477,
  "sub": "John.Doe@my-company.com.au"
}.[Signature]
```

Neither of which have the `access_as_staff` scope.

If I configure the client and API code to use the Portal Client clientId (ec0441a4-89ac-1111-1111-111111111111) and submit the access token to an `[Authorize]` route on the web API I get the following error;

***IDW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token.***

If however I configure the API to use the Portal API clientId (d1a138a9-2379-1111-1111-111111111111) and the client to use the Portal Client clientId (ec0441a4-89ac-1111-1111-111111111111) as shown in the example, I get the following error;

***IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'ec0441a4-89ac-1111-1111-111111111111'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'd1a138a9-2379-1111-1111-111111111111' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.***

Comment: In validationParameters.ValidAudience in API , try giving both clientId of client app and its appId uri

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:***

I tried to change the scope parameter but still I received .
In my case I am calling graph api:
So my scope must be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

I got the same error when I tried to call an API from my web app.

[image]

**Error:**

```
SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'xxx'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: xxxx or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: xxxx
```

In my case I have given wrong clientId in my clientApp registration in

***appsettings.json***

```
  {
    "AzureAd": {
      "Instance": "....",
      "Domain": "xxx",
      "ClientId": "xxx",
      "TenantId": "xxxf3a0cxxb0",
      "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "ClientCertificates": [
      ],
      ….
    },
```

Make sure to expose the scopes for your API  in your API configuration .
Give that (exposed)API permissions to the APP that is clientAPP .

Also check the issuer endpoint,

```
"iss": "https://<b2cTenantName>.b2clogin.com/xxxx/v2.0/",
```

If it has v2 endpoint make sure , the  value is 2 in> "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,

[image]

With all changes , I could call my Api successfully:

[image]
Also check this **reference** : [Azure AD B2C: Call an ASP.NET Web API from an ASP.NET Web App - Code Samples | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/azure-ad-b2c-call-an-aspnet-web-api-from-an-aspnet-web-app/)

Comment: Also please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/azure-ad-b2c-call-an-aspnet-web-api-from-an-aspnet-web-app/#:~:text=demo%20tenant%20environment.-,Known%20Issues,-MSAL%20cache%20needs) known issue  and [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/getting-the-scopes-and-audiences-correct-when-calling-an-api-in-azure-ad-b2c-fe4fb14a10d8)